# html page can not find angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the below code in a html page, running it though I keep getting an error stating that "angular is not defined"  I have included angular in the head so i'm not sure why it can't locate it, the url to angular i'm also able to hit directly.

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html ng-app="test">
<head>
    <title>
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.25/angular.js"></script>
    </title>
</head>
    <body ng-controller="TestController">
    
        <form name="CopyFile" ng-submit="copy(fileId)">
            <input type="text" ng-model="fileId"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Copy"/>    
        </form>

        <div>{{ message }}</div>
        
        <div>{{ error }}</div>
      
    <script type="text/javascript">

        (function () {

            var app = angular.module("test", []);

            var testController = function ($scope, $http) {

                $scope.copy = function (fileId) {
                    $http.get("http://localhost/test/copy/prod.aspx/ToProd?fileId=" + fileId)
                .then(onComplete, onError);
                };

                var onComplete = function (response) {
                    $scope.message = response;
                };

                var onError = function (reason) {
                    $scope.error = "File could not be copied " + reason;
                };
            };

            app.controller("TestController", ["$scope", "$http"], testController);

        } ());

    </script>      
      
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be the cause but you don't want your angular include inside of your title. It should be something more like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html ng-app="test">
<head>
    <title>My Page</title>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.25/angular.js"></script>
</head>
.....
```

Comment: Ugh, I can't believe I didn't see that!

Comment: It's often way too easy to overlook the obvious :)

Comment: You also have a typo in the controller method definition. The closing brace `]` is not correct. It should be `app.controller("TestController", ["$scope", "$http", testController]);`

Comment: @AWolf fixed as you said, it was off.

Answer (score 1):

You gave `<script>` inside `<title>`?

```
<title>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.25/angular.js"></script>
</title>
```

Please remove it outside.